# Getting an error while reading xml document using readxml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

Getting an error while reading xml document using readxml

Some existing code for reference

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.LoadXml("abc.xml");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ds.ReadXml(doc1);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

It gives error that readxml does not have valid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `doc1.LoadXml("abc.xml")` is going to fail; that should be `.Load("abc.xml")` instead (the string `"abc.xml"` is *not* xml - it is a path).

`ReadXml` has a [lot of overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx), but none for taking an `XmlDocument`. Perhaps give it a node-reader instead. Or simpler, perhaps just give it the stream or string:

```
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("abc.xml")){
            ds.ReadXml(file);
        }
```

no `XmlDocument` needed...